# Algorithm used in Excel Fuzzy Lookup

Tags: python, excel, levenshtein-distance, fuzzy-logic

I was working on matching company names of two sets. I was trying to code it in Python with Levenstien's distance. I was having issues with short names of companies, and their trailing part like Pvt,Ltd. I have ran the same set with Excel Fuzzy lookup and was getting good results. I there a way that i can see how excel fuzzy lookup is coded and use the same implementation in python.

Comment: No, Excel is not open-source. Microsoft wants people to pay for their products, so why would they make it possible to get their source code?

Comment: No, since Excel is closed source, but you could research and see if the Microsoft documentation details the algorithm used.

Answer (score 3):

The following is an excerpt from **Microsoft Fuzzy Lookup Add-In for Excel**, Readme.docx. I hope that helps.

> Advanced Concepts
>
> Fuzzy Lookup technology is based upon a very simple, yet flexible
>   measure of similarity between two records. Jaccard similarity  Fuzzy
>   Lookup uses Jaccard similarity, which is defined as the size of the
>   set intersection divided by the size of the set union for two sets of
>   objects. For example, the sets {a, b, c} and {a, c, d} have a Jaccard
>   similarity of 2/4 = 0.5 because the intersection is {a, c} and the
>   union is {a, b, c, d}. The more that the two sets have in common, the
>   closer the Jaccard similarity will be to 1.0.
>
> Weighted Jaccard similarity and tokenization of records  With Fuzzy
>   Lookup, you can assign weights to each item in a set and define the
>   weighted Jaccard similarity as the total weight of the intersection
>   divided by the total weight of the union. For the weighted sets {(a,
>   2), (b, 5), (c, 3)}, {(a, 2), (c, 3), (d, 7)}, the weighted Jaccard
>   similariyt is (2 + 3)/(2 + 3 + 5 +7) = 5/17 = .294.
>
> Because Jaccard similarity is defined over sets, Fuzzy Lookup must
>   first convert data records to sets before it calculates the Jaccard
>   similarity. Fuzzy Lookup converts the data to sets using a Tokenizer.
>   For example, the record {“Jesper Aaberg”, “4567 Main Street”} might be
>   tokenized into the set, {“ Jesper”, “Aaberg”, “4567”, “Main”,
>   “Street”}. The default tokenizer is for English text, but one may
>   change the LocaleId property in Configure=>Global Settings to specify
>   tokenizers for other languages.
>
> Token weighting  Because not all tokens are of equal importance, Fuzzy
>   Lookup assigns weights to tokens. Tokens are assigned high weights if
>   they occur infrequently in a sample of records and low weights if they
>   occur frequently. For example, frequent words such as “Corporation”
>   might be given lower weight, while less frequent words such as
>   “Abracadabra” might be given a higher weight. One may override the
>   default token weights by supplying their own table of token weights.
>
> Transformations Transformations greatly increase the power of Jaccard
>   similarity by allowing tokens to be converted from one string to
>   another. For instance, one might know that the name “Bob” can be
>   converted to “Robert”; that “USA” is the same as “United States”; or
>   that “Missispi” is a misspelling of “Mississippi”. There are many
>   classes of such transformations that Fuzzy Lookup handles
>   automatically such as spelling mistakes (using Edit Transformations
>   described below), string prefixes, and string merge/split operations.
>   You can also specify a table containing your own custom
>   transformations.
>
> Jaccard similarity under transformations  The Jaccard similarity under
>   transformations is the maximum Jaccard similarity between any two
>   transformations of each set. Given a set of transformation rules, all
>   possible transformations of the set are considered. For example, for
>   the sets {a, b, c} and {a, c, d} and the transformation rules {b=>d,
>   d=>e}, the Jaccard similarity is computed as follows: Variations of
>   {a, b, c}: {a, b, c}, {a, d, c} Variations of {a, c, d}: {a, c, d},
>   {a, c, e} Maximum Jaccard similarity between all pairs: J({a, b, c},
>   {a, c, d}) = 2/4 = 0.5 J({a, b, c}, {a, c, e}) = 2/4 = 0.5 J({a, d,
>   c}, {a, c, d}) = 3/3 = 1.0 J({a, d, c}, {a, c, e}) = 2/4 = 0.5 The
>   maximum is 1.0. Note: Weghted Jaccard similiary under transformations
>   is simply the maximum weighted Jaccard similarity across all pairs of
>   transformed sets.
>
> Edit distance  Edit distance is the total number of character
>   insertions, deletions, or substitutions that it takes to convert one
>   string to another. For example, the edit distance between “misissipi”
>   and “mississippi” is 2 because two character insertions are required.
>   One of the transformation providers that’s included with Fuzzy Lookup
>   is the EditTransformationProvider, which generates specific
>   transformations for each input record and creates a transformation
>   from the token to all words in its dictionary that are within a given
>   edit distance. The normalized edit distance is the edit distance
>   divided by the length of the input string. In the previous example,
>   the normalized edit distance is 2/9 = .222.

Answer (score 1):

As I know Fuzzy Lookup use Jaccard similarity. Look into its documentation. As I play around you can also try [SequenceMatcher](http://epydoc.sourceforge.net/stdlib/difflib.SequenceMatcher-class.html#ratio) and play with similarity levels - it gives very nice results after some unifying text strings.